# Concatenate For Loop Counter in Range variable

Tags: excel, vba

I would need help to concatenate myV1 = p1.Value with variable 'j' from the for loop
like myV1= "p" & j & ".value".

Its giving type mismatch error

please help

```
Sub MyPrg()

Dim myVol As Range
Dim p1 As Range
Dim p2 As Range
Dim p3 As Range
Dim myV1 As Long
Dim i, j As Integer

Set myVol = Range("G3")
    
Set p1 = myVol.Offset(1, -1)
Set p2 = myVol.Offset(1, 0)
Set p3 = myVol.Offset(1, 1)

If myVol = 1000000 Then
  
p1.Value = myVol.Value * 40 / 100
p2.Value = myVol.Value * 40 / 100
p3.Value = myVol.Value * 20 / 100

For j = 1 To 3

myV1 = p1.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
Sub MyPrg()

Dim myVol As Range
Dim p(1 to 3) As Range
Dim myV1 As Long
Dim I As Integer, j As Integer

Set myVol = Range("G3")
    
Set p(1) = myVol.Offset(1, -1)
Set p(2) = myVol.Offset(1, 0)
Set p(3) = myVol.Offset(1, 1)

If myVol = 1000000 Then
  
p(1).Value = myVol.Value * 40 / 100
p(2).Value = myVol.Value * 40 / 100
p(3).Value = myVol.Value * 20 / 100

For j = 1 To 3

myV1 = p(j).Value
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes - thank you. Trying to do too many things at once.